# armv7-m bare metal ldr/str symbolic memory

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7

so I know questions for ldr/str on arm are countless. Perhaps this is another twist (not probable) or I'm just missing something (more probable.)

So this is bare metal and I want to load/store some variable in memory. And because I insist I want to give it a name. Naively I could write:

```
.section .bss
var: .word 0

.section .text
str r0, var
```

(having a custom linker script which puts .bss in ram and .text in flash)

Of cause this doesn't work because instructions are 32bit and only have place for some smaller immediate. And the instructions I'm talking about live in flash which is 0x8000000+x and the variable is to be stored in memory which is somewhere in the 0x20000000+y.

Manually I know quite some ways to solve this:

- storing the variables address in a constant (`varaddr: .word 0x2001234; ldr r1, [pc,#varaddr]; str r0, [r1]`)
- loading ram-base in a register and addressing it relative (`ldr r1, #0x20000000; str r0, [r1,#varoffset]`)
- construct the address by arithmetic (`mov r1, #0x2000000; add r1, #offset / orr / movw / movt something`)
- certainly quite some more

Every of these variants work but neither of these variants let me use the label which I really want to use.

So what am I missing here. Is my idea for the linker script and labels bogus? Is there some assembler feature I didn't see? Something completely different?

Comment: Use `ldr r1, =var` to get the address, then work with that.  Alternatively, program the same thing in C and see what the compiler does, then do the same.  Yes, you will not be able to use the label name when you actually modify the variable.  I suggest making a macro for the register number if you want a symbolic name.

Comment: ARMv7 can construct an arbitrary 32-bit value (e.g. an address) in a register with `movw` (wide immediate) + `movk` or something like that.  Compilers will sometimes use that instead of a PC-relative load from a nearby constant pool when optimizing for some ARM CPUs.

Comment: @Peter: Thats what I meant with my third bullet point.

Comment: @fuz: The compiler does what I have at the first bullet point. It stores the ram address in flash and uses that. ```ldr r1, =var``` the same. Is this the best what can be done?

Comment: @Scheintod The other way is to use a `movw; movt` pair (you can generate these using appropriate relocations without having to know the address).  It is not possible to use an arbitrary memory address directly.

Comment: One thing you could do is put all your variables next to each other in a structure and load one register with the base address of the structure.  You can then access all variables symbolically using a symbol for the offset from the beginning of the structure.

Comment: Alternatively you can put your variables into registers and use symbolic names for the registers.  This only works if you have enough registers.

Comment: @fuz: Perhaps this is could be (?) what I want. (Do you mind some example code because perhaps I neither know how to use movw/movt symbolically nor how to use structs symbolically. In assembler anyway. Maybe thats what I'm missing...)

Comment: @Scheintod Hm... which assembler do you use?  I can certainly make an example.

Comment: @fuz: gcc-as. (btw: I'm still finding the different dialects confusion. But starting to get used to it.) I just found the :upper16: / :lower16: idiom. Is that what you ment for movw/movt? How would you access structure members symbolically? (sorry. been using assembler sporadically for some time now but new to thumb2)

Comment: @Scheintod Yeah, `:upper16:` and `:lower16:`.   You should have said up front that you were programming in thumb mode!  This changes a few things.  My bad again for making assumptions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209407/discussion-between-scheintod-and-fuz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could use symbolic names for variables in static storage is to define a structure for your variables.  This allows you to load the base address of your structure into a register and then access structure members using symbolic names relative to the base address.  For example, you could do:

```
        .struct 0          @ start a new structure
foo:    .skip 4            @ length of foo
bar:    .skip 4            @ length of bar
baz:    .skip 4            @ length of baz
len:                       @ total length of the structure

        .section .bss      @ switch to the BSS (uninitialised data) section
        .balign 4          @ align to 4 bytes
variables:
        .space len         @ reserve space for your variables

        .section .text     @ switch to the text (code) section

        ...
        ldr r0, =variables @ load r0 with the base address of your variables
        ldr r1, [r0+#foo]  @ access foo
        str r2, [r0+#bar]  @ access bar
        ldr r3, [r0+#baz]  @ access baz
```

This is pretty much the closest you can get to symbolic names for variables in static storage.  If the variables are on the stack, you can use a similar approach using the frame pointer (or stack pointer) as the base address.  The operand to `.struct` is the base address of the structure for which you can chose any value you like.

As for `movw` and `movt`.  These offer a tiny performance advantage on some microarchitectures over `ldr ..., =...` as they do not require data fetches to the text section.  This makes no difference on armv7-m targets as far as I know; also, `movw` and `movt` consume two extra bytes versus `ldr` with an `=` operand.  I thus recommend you to stick with `ldr` and an `=` operand.  The usage of `movw` and `movt` is like this:

```
        movw r0, :lower16:foo  @ load lower 16 bit of foo's address into r0
        movt r0, :upper16:foo  @ or higher 16 bit of foo's address into r0
```

These two have to be issued in this specific order as `movw` clears the upper 16 bit.  The prefixes `:lower16:` and `:upper16:` select appropriate relocation types referring to just the lower and upper 16 bit of the symbol's address.  You can make a macro to make this easier to type:

```
        .macro addr reg, sym
        movw \reg, :lower16:\sym
        movt \reg, :upper16:\sym
        .endm
```

This allows you to write

```
        addr r0, foo
```

to generate the aforementioned `movw` and `movt` pair.

Comment: Looks very nice. Do you have a refence/tutorial/manual/better docs/reading recommendation on these directives? What I found is pretty thin.

Comment: @Scheintod Read the [GNU assembler manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/).

Comment: That's what I meant with thin. Your example is telling me much more than this: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Struct.html#Struct

Comment: @Scheintod I used exactly that reference, nothing more.  `.struct` allows you to conveniently define absolute symbols (i.e. like if you used `.equ`) without having to manually calculate addresses.  To be honest, the example on that site is a bit misleading, but I haven't found a good one either.  Few people seem to use this directive.

Comment: Apart from this, the best trick to learn how to do things is to write up the code in C, compile it to assembly and inspect the output.  There are ABI documents too, but they are often very long and hard to understand.

Comment: @[few people]: perhaps because this is (if I understand it correctly) mostly equivalent to ```foo=0; bar=4; baz=8; len=12; ...``` but with automagic taking care of len when inserting/deleting. It all breaks down to my second bullet point but it's symbolic which I like at least better than nothing. (And I do like the macro alternative, too).

Comment: @Scheintod Yeah, exactly.  Macros to define structures basically work like this in all assemblers.